# percentage max-height on image ignored in firefox

Tags: css, image, firefox, responsive-design

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <article class="article">
        <img class="article-img" src="bordeaux.jpg" />
    </article>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.container{
    width:500px;
    height:200px;
}
.article{
    max-height:100%;
}
.article-img{
    max-height:100%;
}
```

see its jsfiddle in **Firefox**

http://jsfiddle.net/UETMr/4/

I needed to set **.article to height:100%** for image to shrink in Firefox

can someone explain how does firefox understand percentage max-height and its containers ?

thanks in advance !

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It understands it the way [the W3C specifications state](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-max-height). For `max-height` to work, something other than the content itself needs to be explicitly setting the `height` of its containing element. This is why when you set `height: 100%` it works, because now you are explicitly telling `.article` to take its `height` from its parent (rather than its content). But when you have `.article` set with `max-height`, then it is still the content driving its calculated `height`, just with the limitation of not sizing past the `.container` `height`. And in your case, the content is the `img` itself.

[In this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UETMr/8/), you can see that the `.article` is in fact constraining itself to the `height` of `.container`, but is allowing the content of itself (the `img`) to overflow to a larger height. The `img` is not constrained by its `max-height` because `.article` does not have an *explicit* `height` set, but is in fact getting its height from the `img` (only it is limited that it cannot go past the `height` of its container).