# Why am I not getting scrolling in this div?

Tags: html, css, angularjs, formatting, scroll

In [How can I get a div that treats line breaks as significant to scroll if it exceeds a certain height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25089663/how-can-i-get-a-div-that-treats-line-breaks-as-significant-to-scroll-if-it-excee), I thought I'd isolated a simple test case for the issue I am running into, namely `DIV`s with `max-height` and scroll of auto set. However, while the answer to [How can I get a div that treats line breaks as significant to scroll if it exceeds a certain height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25089663/how-can-i-get-a-div-that-treats-line-breaks-as-significant-to-scroll-if-it-excee) results in unchanged behavior: the `div` contents in question are however tall their content is, and do not seem to scroll. So let me give my source code:

**The CSS:**

```
<style type="text/css">
    div.user{
        height: 30%;
        max-height: 30%;
        overflow-y: scroll;
        white-space: pre-wrap;
    }
    div.user div.text{
        height: 30%;
        max-height: 30%;
        overflow-y: scroll;
    }
    input[type='text'] {
        width: 100%;
    }
    textarea {
        width: 100%;
        height: 150px;
    }
</style>
```

**The source HTML:**

```
<div class='user' ng-repeat='session in sessions'>
    <div class='text' ng-bind='monologues[session][0]'></div>
    <div class='timestamp' ng-bind='monologues[session][1] | to_locale'></div>
</div>
```

**What you get by Chrome's Inspect Element:**

```
<div class="user ng-scope" ng-repeat="session in sessions">
    <div class="text ng-binding" ng-bind="monologues[session][0]">a
    b
    c
    d
    h
    i
    j
    k
    l
    m
    n
    o
    p
    q
    r
    s
    t
    </div>
    <div class="timestamp ng-binding" ng-bind="monologues[session][1] | to_locale">6/19/2014 1:14:30 PM</div>
</div>
```

I've tried a few permutations, but I don't see how this is different from my minimal test case.

What should be changed so that either div.user or div.text is 30% tall?

Thanks,

Comment: I think you have to give the parent a height. Take a look at the answer on this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20507718/percentage-max-height-on-image-ignored-in-firefox).

Comment: A codepen or jsfiddle would help solve this problem more quickly. A quick suggestion is to try `overflow-y: auto`. also keep in mind that 'pre-wrap` is honors whitespace, so this could potentially cause overflow on x axis.

Comment: Does the parent element have a height? You shouldn't need to declare a height and a max-height of the same value. You only need `height: 30%`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a demo of what I mean. You should declare a height on el or parent, else the content just fills the div, which also stcks out so well b/c you're using `pre-wrap`

```
div.user{
    border: 1px solid tomato;
    height: 300px;
    overflow: auto;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}
div.user div.text{
    height: 30%;
    border: 1px solid #bada55;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
input[type='text'] {
    width: 100%;
}
textarea {
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
}
```

http://codepen.io/presstep/pen/pCDtx

**TL;DR**: without explicitly declaring a height, the browser sees no reason to do anything other than make the div large enough to hold its content.